# How to add Commas in Python?

Tags: python

I have this code finished and it runs fine, i just cannot figure out how to add commas into each dollar value.]

Here are pics of the code: [Pic 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcGru.png)
                           [Pic 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8T2AR.png)

Any help would be great,
Thanks.

Comment: It would be better if you posted the code here rather than a pic to it.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to format the float numbers yourself.

Or use `babel.numbers.format_currency`, from the [Babel](http://babel.pocoo.org/en/latest/index.html) library. See: http://babel.pocoo.org/en/latest/api/numbers.html

Example:

```
>>> format_currency(1099.98, 'USD', locale='en_US')
u'$1,099.98'
```

You can also use this format:

```
print ("${:,.2f}".format(1234.56))
# -> $1,234.56
```